# How to check that function is at a minimum given certain values (matrix/vector calculus)?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, vectors, matrix-calculus, maxima-minima

I have the following matrices and vectors:

$ C \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2} $

$ \vec{d} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $

$ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $

And I have the following function:

$$ f_1(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T C \vec{x} - \vec{x}^T \vec{x} + \vec{d}^T \vec{x}$$

I need to develop a function where I can check whether the function $f_1$ has a minimum when we provide some $d, e,$ and $C$.

I know that the first derivative w.r.t. $\vec{x}$ of this function is:

$$
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial \vec{x}}
   = 2 \vec{x}^TC - 2 \vec{x}^T + \vec{d}^T
$$

And that the second derivative w.r.t. $\vec{x}$ of this function is:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial \vec{x}^2}
   = 2C - 2I
$$

However, at this point I am completely lost as to how to determine whether this point can be a minimum or not.

Usually I would develop a Hessian matrix, except I only have one variable ($\vec{x}$). I understand that the second partial derivative test is typically used to check for whether a point is the minimum, but how can I do this here when I have a vector ($\vec{x}$) instead of a scalar?

I am confused on how to calculate a determinant or check if it is positive definite when using a matrix instead of a scalar. Could someone please clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the definition of $f$ we have
$$\begin{align}
f(x_1,x_2)&=\vec{x}^T C \vec{x} - \vec{x}^T \vec{x} + \vec{d}^T \vec{x}\\
&=c_{1,1}x_1^2+(c_{1,2}+c_{2,1})x_1x_2+c_{2,2}x_2^2-x_1^2-x_2^2+d_1x_1+d_2x_2
\end{align}$$
where $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2)$.
Is it more familiar in that way?

It follows that
$$\begin{align}
\nabla f(x_1,x_2)&=(2(c_{1,1}-1)x_1+(c_{1,2}+c_{2,1})x_2+d_1,2(c_{2,2}-1)x_2+(c_{1,2}+c_{2,1})x_1+d_2)\\
&=(C+C^T-2I)\vec{x}+\vec{d}
\end{align}$$
and
$$H_f(x_1,x_2)=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    2(c_{1,1}-1) & c_{1,2}+c_{2,1} \\
    c_{1,2}+c_{2,1} & 2(c_{2,2}-1) \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]=C+C^T-2I.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This makes a lot more sense thank you! But I have to ask - what if $\vec(x)$ is much larger? Is there no way to handle these kind of calculations in vector/matrix format?

Comment: @user745587 I wrote also the result in vector format (which hold in $\mathbb{R}^n$)